# Limitar tamanho de imagens

Tags: css

Tenho uma listagem de notícias e precisaria que todas as imagens fossem limitadas por um **height**, mas não posso definir um valor específico, se não a imagem pode esticar.
Todas as imagens devem ter o mesmo tamanho e largura. Pode cortar se for o caso.

Como fazer?

```css
item h1,
.blog h1 {
  font: 40px/40px "Niemeyer-BoldIt";
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.blog span {
  font: 12px/12px "Niemeyer-Regular";
  color: #000;
}

.news li {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-destaque-listagem {
  width: 100%;
}

a.noticia-destaque {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30.33%;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.noticias-destaque {
  font-size: 0;
}

.noticia-destaque h3 {
  font: 15px/17px 'Niemeyer-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-data {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.novidade-texto p {
  font: 15px/25px 'Niemeyer-Light', sans-serif;
}

.novidade-texto img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticias-destaque">
  <a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-title">
    <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a6ebc2753ed_900x.jpg);"></span>
    <span class="info">

        <div class="novidade-texto">
                             <img src="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/ceciestuntest2-1212011503842739-8/95/teste-de-inteligencia-1-728.jpg?cb=1211986860" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
                                     <span class="info-data">29/08</span>
    <h3>post title </h3>
</div>
</span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-teste">
  <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a0db9ff74_900x.jpg);"></span>
  <span class="info">

        <div class="novidade-texto">
                             <img src="http://www.montatudo.com/i/montatudo/9931161998_266231.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
                                     <span class="info-data">29/08</span>
  <h3>post teste </h3>
  </div>
  </span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-tste-2">
  <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a030249da_900x.jpg);"></span>
  <span class="info">

        <div class="novidade-texto">
                             <img src="http://www.montatudo.com/i/montatudo/9931161998_266231.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
                                     <span class="info-data">29/08</span>
  <h3>post tste 2</h3>
  </div>
  </span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-teste">
  <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a00003656_900x.jpg);"></span>
  <span class="info">

        <div class="novidade-texto">
                             <img src="/uploads/imagens/59a5a00003656_900x.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
                                     <span class="info-data">29/08</span>
  <h3>Post teste</h3>
  </div>
  </span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `max-height` não resolve o problema?

Comment: @white estica a imagem.

Comment: a imagem tem que ficar em tamanho original e apenas ajustar a div? Ou a imagem tem q se ajustar ao tamanho da div?

Comment: A imagem tem que se ajustar conforme a div.

Comment: complicou, vc diz na pergunta "Todas as imagens devem ter o mesmo tamanho e largura" e no comentario diz "A imagem tem que se ajustar conforme a div"

Comment: Na verdade, a imagem tem que se basear no tamanho da div. O ideal é que na listagem tudo tivesse o mesmo tamanho, entende?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir uma altura-máxima (`max-height`) às imagens na classe `.novidade-texto img`:

```
.novidade-texto img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px; /*Por exemplo, 100px máximo*/
}
```

MAS, também não deve definir uma largura (`width`) nas mesmas imagens como você está fazendo na classe abaixo:

```
.img-destaque-listagem {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Apague esta classe acima.

```css
item h1,
.blog h1 {
  font: 40px/40px "Niemeyer-BoldIt";
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.blog span {
  font: 12px/12px "Niemeyer-Regular";
  color: #000;
}

.news li {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-destaque-listagem {
}

a.noticia-destaque {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30.33%;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.noticias-destaque {
  font-size: 0;
}

.noticia-destaque h3 {
  font: 15px/17px 'Niemeyer-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-data {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.novidade-texto p {
  font: 15px/25px 'Niemeyer-Light', sans-serif;
}

.novidade-texto img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticias-destaque">
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-title">
<span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a6ebc2753ed_900x.jpg);"></span>
<span class="info">
<div class="novidade-texto">
<img src="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/ceciestuntest2-1212011503842739-8/95/teste-de-inteligencia-1-728.jpg?cb=1211986860" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
<h3>post title </h3>
</div>
</span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-teste">
<span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a0db9ff74_900x.jpg);"></span>
<span class="info">

<div class="novidade-texto">
<img src="http://www.montatudo.com/i/montatudo/9931161998_266231.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
<h3>post teste </h3>
</div>
</span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-tste-2">
<span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a030249da_900x.jpg);"></span>
<span class="info">

<div class="novidade-texto">
<img src="http://www.montatudo.com/i/montatudo/9931161998_266231.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
<h3>post tste 2</h3>
</div>
</span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-teste">
<span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a00003656_900x.jpg);"></span>
<span class="info">

<div class="novidade-texto">
<img src="/uploads/imagens/59a5a00003656_900x.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
<h3>Post teste</h3>
</div>
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Quase isso. Teria como deixar as imagens com 100% de width?

Comment: Veja bem: se vc quer que todas as imagens tenham o mesmo width e height, as imagens que tiverem dimensões diferentes vão ficar esticadas.

Comment: Se uma ultrapassar a altura, teria como cortar ela?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Teria se vc criasse uma div no lugar da imagem e fizesse da imagem um background dessa div.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Veja esse Fiddle. No exemplo, eu setei em 150px a div: https://jsfiddle.net/v4mfd8x8/

Answer (score 1):

O @Dvdsamm deu uma excelente solução. Peguei o exemplo dele para te dar uma alternativa caso queira "cropar" as imagens a cima de 100px.

A mudança que fiz foi adicionar a div com classe `img-overflow` fora de todas as suas imagens e definir:

```
.img-overflow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

E deixei suas imagens assim:

```
.novidade-texto img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Desta forma, ele pega cria suas imagens com `width: 100%;` e altura máxima proporcionalmente e centraliza elas verticalmente.

```css
item h1,
.blog h1 {
  font: 40px/40px "Niemeyer-BoldIt";
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.blog span {
  font: 12px/12px "Niemeyer-Regular";
  color: #000;
}

.news li {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-destaque-listagem {
  width: 100%;
}

a.noticia-destaque {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30.33%;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.noticias-destaque {
  font-size: 0;
}

.noticia-destaque h3 {
  font: 15px/17px 'Niemeyer-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info-data {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.novidade-texto p {
  font: 15px/25px 'Niemeyer-Light', sans-serif;
}

.img-overflow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.novidade-texto img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="noticias-destaque">
  <a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-title">
    <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a6ebc2753ed_900x.jpg);"></span>
    <span class="info">
<div class="novidade-texto">
<div class="img-overflow">
<img src="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/ceciestuntest2-1212011503842739-8/95/teste-de-inteligencia-1-728.jpg?cb=1211986860" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
</div>
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
    <h3>post title </h3>
</div>
</span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-teste">
  <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a0db9ff74_900x.jpg);"></span>
  <span class="info">

<div class="novidade-texto">
<div class="img-overflow">
<img src="http://www.montatudo.com/i/montatudo/9931161998_266231.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
</div>
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
  <h3>post teste </h3>
  </div>
  </span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-tste-2">
  <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a030249da_900x.jpg);"></span>
  <span class="info">

<div class="novidade-texto">
<div class="img-overflow">
<img src="http://www.montatudo.com/i/montatudo/9931161998_266231.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
</div>
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
  <h3>post tste 2</h3>
  </div>
  </span>
</a>
<a class="noticia-destaque" href="/noticias/2017-08-29/post-teste">
  <span class="img" style="background-image: url(/uploads/imagens/59a5a00003656_900x.jpg);"></span>
  <span class="info">

<div class="novidade-texto">
<div class="img-overflow">
<img src="/uploads/imagens/59a5a00003656_900x.jpg" class="img-destaque img-destaque-listagem">
</div>
<span class="info-data">29/08</span>
  <h3>Post teste</h3>
  </div>
  </span>
</a>
</div>
```